# Is there such a number N such that any group of order N is simple?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Is there such a number N, such that any group of order N is simple?

Comment: Take for example $N=2$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas   
Do you have an example s.t N is not prime?

Comment: Well, there is the even duller $N=1$. There is no composite $N$, since there is always an abelian group of order $N$, and if $N$ is composite any abelian group of order $N$ is not simple.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Thank you!

Comment: But, according to standard terminology,  the group of order $1$ is not simple, for the same sorts of reasons that $1$ is not a prime number.

Comment: For that matter there is the *even duller* $N = 0$. There are no such groups, so a statement about "any group of order 0" is vacuously true ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A more subtle question would be: are there any natural numbers $N$, such that all the *non-abelian groups* of order $N$ are simple?

Note that for infinite many $N$, there do not exist any non-abelian groups of order $N$, for example if $N$ is the square of a prime or gcd$(N,\varphi(N))=1$.

But suppose the set $\{G: G \text{ is a non-abelian group with } |G|=N\}$ is non-empty. Can it be the case? The answer is *no*! We may assume $N \gt 2$. Let $G$ be a non-abelian simple group of order $N$. Then $|N|$ must be even (this is due to the deep [Odd-Order Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feit%E2%80%93Thompson_theorem) of Feit and Thompson), say $N=2M$ with $M \gt 1$. If $M \geq 3$, then the dihedral group of order $N$, $D_{M}=\langle a,b: a^{M}=1=b^2, b^{-1}ab=a^{-1}\rangle$, is a non-abelian group of order $N$ and is certainly not simple (for example $\langle a \rangle \lhd D_{M}$). Hence $M=2$, so $N=4$, but all groups of order $4$ are abelian, a contradiction.

Fun fact to know: there are non-isomorphic simple groups of the same order: $A_8 \cong PSL(4,2)$ and $PSL(3,4)$ of order $20160$.

Comment: Thank you very much, this answer is very intriguing

Comment: You are welcome Joseph! You asked a good question (+1 from me!) and actually the relation between the order of a group and its intrinsic group theoretical structure has been studied a lot - see for example http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.30.4997&rep=rep1&type=pdf

Comment: Thank you, you are really helpful! I will see that!

Answer (score 9):

There are abelian groups of any order, and an abelian group which is not of prime order is not simple.

Comment: Wow, this answer eliminates lots of groups!

Answer (score 6):

If $N$ is prime, then any group of order $N$ is unique up to isomorphism and is simple and cyclic! You can also take $N=1$, the trivial group is also simple.

Comment: Do you have an example s.t  N is not prime?

Comment: The trivial group is not simple.

Comment: @DerekHolt Ok, thank you